# General inequality about two positive numbers

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Given two numbers $x,y \in \mathbb{R}_{+}$, it's easy to see that $$\frac{1}{y}-\frac{1}{x} \geq \frac{1}{x} - \frac{y}{x^2}$$ no matter what $x,y$ are as long as they are positives.

Simply $$ \frac{1}{y}+\frac{y}{x^2}-\frac{2}{x} = \frac{x^2 +y^2 -2 x y}{x^2 y} = \frac{(x-y)^2}{x^2 y} \geq 0 $$

But is there something in the other direction meaning $$f(x,y) \geq \frac{1}{y}-\frac{1}{x}$$, such that $f$ is continuous and differentiable function ?, obvious questions like $$\Bigg| \frac{1}{y}-\frac{1}{x}\Bigg|$$ are not allowed.

Thanks.

Comment: I think $\frac{x}{y^2}-\frac{1}{y} $ will do the job.

Comment: Yup.$\; \; \; \; $